# css image hover link

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, css

I have an image, and then a series of links. The hover works as intended on the text links, but when I place it on an image, in chrome and safari it only changes the background color for a portion of the image, not the whole thing...which I really dont understand. I tried jsfiddle as well as some of the other tools mentioned on SO, please look at the code below if you know why this is happening:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Welcome!</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #header {
        background-color:#2C2C2C;
        height:88px;
        width:100%;
        margin: 0px auto 0 auto;
    }
    #header_logo_link {
        float: left;
        width: 250px;
    }
    #header_logo_link img {
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        background: transparent;
    }
    #header_logo_link :hover {
        background-color: #4d4d4d;
    }
    body, .wrapper {
        min-height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;

        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        min-height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="header_logo_link">
            <a href="/"><img src="logo.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="header_logo_link">
            <a href="/home">Home</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?  you can't change the color of an image?  do you want to change the color around the image?

Comment: The problem is that the hover is not covering the whole image..only a part of it. When I have a hover on the text its fine. This problem is only for chrome and safari.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ninty9notout/n2SHh/ If you are then I can explain more about what I did here.

Comment: YES! that's exactly what I'm trying to implement.

Comment: If you put that as an answer, i'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but if you're trying to change the color around the image when it's rolled over, try adding some padding to the a element and display:block.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Welcome!</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #header {
        background-color:#2C2C2C;
        height:88px;
        width:100%;
        margin: 0px auto 0 auto;
    }
    #header_logo_link {
        float: left;
        width: 250px;
    }
    #header_logo_link img {
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        background: transparent;
    }
    #header_logo_link :hover {
        background-color: #4d4d4d;
    }
    body, .wrapper {
        min-height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;

        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        min-height: 100%;
    }
    a.img_rollover{
        padding:5px;
        display:block;
    }
    a.img_rollover:hover{
        background-color: #00F; /*This is your new rollover color*/
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="header_logo_link" class="img_rollover">
            <a href="/"><img src="logo.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="header_logo_link">
            <a href="/home">Home</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, this is experiencing the same issue. The image is not getting fully covered by the hover back ground changing.

Comment: your correct, the above code isn't covering the whole image.  You can try creating a div that covers the image, position it relative to it, and have it appear when you are rolling over it and hide when not.